# Download BOM without explicitly adding in pom file

Tags: java, maven, maven-bom

Is there any way to download a BOM file without explicitly adding the BOM file dependency in pom file? I would like to avoid addition of bom dependencies in my pom files. But the latest versions of TPP jars like Spring, CXF seem to have a dependency on BOM files and compilation fails without them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The BOM only defines what version the dependencies should have if you bring them in; it does not actually pull in dependencies. It should be safe to add it.

Comment: If you like to use them you have to add them. If adding of a BOM results in issue there is something else wrong...

Comment: What I don't understand is: ` I would like to avoid addition of bom dependencies in my pom files.`? Why? As I wrote if adding will cause issues there are other problems..

Comment: I need to add many bom files for my application to work....So just looking for a way to not add them explicitly in pom file or rather have them downloaded as a transitive dependency.